# css position vertical navigation left

Tags: css, html

would you be able to help me to position my navigation - "wrapperNav" completely left in the browser so there would be no gap between the blue navigation and the browser edge?
thanks a lot.
code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hKsCe

```
<header>
<div id="logo"><img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="logo"/></div>
<h1 id="adminHeader">Administrace webu</h1>
<div id="wrapperNav">
<nav>   
<ul>
<li>Vložit obrázek</li>
<li>Editovat odkazy</li>
<li>Nahrát soubor</li>
<li>Editovat text</li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
</header>


#logo,
#adminHeader {
float: left; 
display: inline;
width: 45%;
}

    nav li {
list-style: none;
height: 100px;
color: #7E8AA2;
background: #263248;
min-width: 100px;
    }
    nav li:hover {
background: #000;
    }

    #wrapperNav {
margin-top: 70px;
margin-left: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-right: 0;
padding: 0;
position: fixed;
float: left;
display:block;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, you just needed to add in `padding-left: 0px;` to nav ul

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Administrace odkazů</title>
      <link href="adminstyle2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <style type="text/css">
         #logo, #adminHeader {
             float: left;
             display: inline;
             width: 45%;
         }
         nav li {
             list-style: none;
             height: 100px;
             color: #7E8AA2;
             background: #263248;
             min-width: 100px;
         }
         nav li:hover {
            background: #000;
         }
         #wrapperNav {
             margin-top: 70px;
             margin-left: 0;
             margin-bottom: 0;
             margin-right: 0;
             padding: 0;
             position: fixed;
             float: left;
             display:block;
         }
         nav ul {
            padding-left:0px;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <header>
      </header>
      <div id="logo"><img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="logo"/></div>
      <h1 id="adminHeader">Administrace webu</h1>
      <div id="wrapperNav">
         <nav>
            <ul>
               <li>Vložit obrázek</li>
               <li>Editovat odkazy</li>
               <li>Nahrát soubor "credentials"</li>
               <li>Editovat text</li>
            </ul>
         </nav>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#wrapperNav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

As need to be updated, I did on your example, try it once.

As a best practice you have to use css re-set for better styling. Because HTML tags has its own padding and margins, so using a re-set css, you can re--set them and control by yourself. Use following link for more. http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a reset. For example, put in your css:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: I think if he does this, entire structure will be messed.

Comment: If he won't, the website could look different in various browsers

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your code check it.

[http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Dvcgr][1]